# Ошибка при попытке иницилизации rosdep в linux

Tags: python, linux

Модуль *rosdep* предварительно установила. При попытке `sudo rosdep init` из командной строки:

```
**File "/usr/local/bin/rosdep", line 4, in <module>
  __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('rosdep==0.11.2', 'rosdep')
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 735, in run_script
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1644, in run_script
pkg_resources.ResolutionError: No script named 'rosdep'**
```

По адресу `/usr/local/bin/` в числе прочих файлы `rosdep` и `rosdep-source`. Содержимое обоих файлов `rosdep` и `rosdep-source` одинаковое:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-SCRIPT: 'rosdep==0.11.2','rosdep'
__requires__ = 'rosdep==0.11.2'
__import__('pkg_resources').run_script('rosdep==0.11.2', 'rosdep')
```

Answer (score 1):

судя по приведённой информации, вы установили пакет, содержащий в имени слово *rosdep*, в котором находится версия, отличная от 0.11.2, которую запрашивает программа `/usr/local/bin/rosdep`.

вам надо определиться — что именно вам нужно: пакет из репозитория или россыпь файлов/каталогов по файловой системе.

а после этого действовать согласно принятому решению: либо удалить пакет, либо как-то вычистить эти самые вручную раскиданные по файловой системе файлы и каталоги.